# C# sender problems

Tags: c#

When i press a picturebox in my project I contact the method card_Pressed.
 through this code

```
 this.picturebox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.card_Pressed)
```

I have a few pictureboxes as all are linked to this method, now i wanna check which has been pressed by contacting the sender in the method and comparing it to the name of the picturebox.

```
 if( sender == picturebox1)
{
//something
 }
```

I got this working when im using a button but not when im using a picturebox, why?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this work? : `if(object.Equals(sender, picturebox1))`

Comment: try **if((picturebox)sender == picturebox1)**

Comment: We need **more information**. The code you have posted *works*, the error must be elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm.. When i use a button, "base" in sender is the same as the button name. When i do the same with a picturebox i get at base {System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox, SizeMode: StretchImage} System.Windows.Forms.Control {System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox}

Comment: There is no obvious reason why this wouldn't work.  Post code that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Kneed What do you mean by “base”?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Name property of Picture box, `(sender as PictureBox).Name == ...` just if you do a null checking it will be better :

```
var box = (sender as PictureBox);
if (box != null && box.Name == "Blah")
{
  ///
}
```

Comment: Why would OP want to do this?

Comment: if sender is not a PictureBox, won't this throw an exception?

Comment: @IAbstract, first paragraph throws an exception, but my complete answer doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, I think this phrase: "i wanna check which has been pressed by contacting the sender in the method and comparing it to the name of the picturebox" says OP wants this, but why I don't know.

Comment: @Saeed You’re right but the OP *seems* to mean simply comparing the objects (see subsequent code) and in any case, comparing the names of the objects is merely a roundabout way of achieving the same effect.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, you are right but first I don't know why OPs way doesn't work but by his word: "name of the picturebox" I think he searches for specific name, or may be he passes string, so I wrote this, may be my guess is wrong, but it's just my guess.